# How to read a file every 'n' bits in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I need to read a file (from right to left), whose reading range can vary, in some cases it can be every 3 bits, 18 bits, etc...

How to do it?

I'll give an example:

The file is:

```
file : "anyway.rar"
```

The last 10 hexadecimals of this file are:

`1A 2B DF FA 00 15 02 12 EA 1B`

I want to read every 3 bits and from right to left. So we started with `EA 1B` which in binary is:

`11101010 00011011`

The reading would be:

`011 >> 011 >> 000 >> 101...`

If I want to read every 5 bits the reading would be:

`11011 >> 10000 >> 11010...`

The intention is to make a calculation with each group of bits.

Comment: What is wrong with reading the file and dropping all unwanted bits?

Comment: I need to read ALL the bits. With the detail that the reading range will change.

Comment: Can you read the file into an array of bytes, convert each byte to an array of bits, flatten, reverse the array, then read from the array so-many elements at a time?

Comment: What do you mean by _"reading range"_ and _"every 3 bits, 18 bits, etc"_? Can you give an example – how could such file look like and what would be the expected result?

Comment: @talC what is `11011` – a string, the integer `0b11011` i.e. `27`, or something else?

Comment: @Stefan Answering your question will mainly be used as integer (27), as said, it can be anything as the case may be, the important thing is to be able to read it in `n` bits, but yes, integer is more important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a short but not so simple solution.
Allthough you didn't provide code you allready have, I'm sure you have no difficulty reading the string from a file. Some special consideration would have to be made if the input file were binary.

```
def string_to_bits text, chunksize = 8
  StringIO.new(text.unpack('B*').first).each(chunksize).map{|chunk| chunk}
end
```

Some explanation: `String.unpack` formats a string, `B*` means in bits, MostSignificant Bits first. See [here](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/unpack) for the API. It returns an array of one element (hence the following `first`)
This string is converted to an enumarable using `StringIO`, which has an `each(n)` method that chops the string in chunks of the desired length. We convert the enumerator back to an array using map.

Use it like this

```
puts string_to_bits "this is my text"
#=> ["01110100", "01101000", "01101001", "01110011", "00100000", "01101001", "01110011", "00100000", "01101101", "01111001", "00100000", "01110100", "01100101", "01111000", "01110100"]
```

and

```
puts string_to_bits "this is my text", 3
#=> ["011", "101", "000", "110", "100", "001", "101", "001", "011", "100", "110", "010", "000", "001", "101", "001", "011", "100", "110", "010", "000", "001", "101", "101", "011", "110", "010", "010", "000", "001", "110", "100", "011", "001", "010", "111", "100", "001", "110", "100"]
```

[

Comment: And yes, the input is binary.

Comment: for big files you will need to work with a read buffer, plenty of examples to read big binary files here at stackoverflow, it's going to be a long task anyway you do it.It would help if you explain what kind of files are your input, how you are going to process the result and what is the final purpose.